# iphone sdk grab php content

Tags: php, iphone

I have a PHP file which when opened in a browser displays "hello" and nothing more.

I want to grab this content so it will display "hello" on a label on the iPhone.

Can anyone provide a very simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/word"];
NSError *error;

myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```